# How to use calculation in javascript

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, calculation

I have two variables **duration** and **price** ,the **price** starts at **1600** and the **duration** at **30** so once the **duration** is **30** the **price** would be **1600**, I made a switch case to calculate the rest but only for **60** and **90**, I want to know how to calculate the rest by using the switch case.
here's my code:

```
switch(duration){
    case 30:
      var price = 1600;
    break;
    case 60:
      var price = 1600*2;
    break;
  case 90:
      var price = 1600*3;
     break;
  
}
```

Comment: Why not simply `var price = (duration / 3) * 160`? This is basic math. First thing that came to my mind when I saw this code — I didn’t even read your question.

Comment: Yeah, switch case should only be reserved for when you have many many conditions with really different outcomes, not for this kind of calculation

Answer (score 1):

Ditching switch case altogether is the best solution - just do this:

```js
price = duration / 30 * 1600;
```

Just set it proportional to the duration